# Classic ASP sending email with SMTP Authentication

Tags: asp-classic, smtp

We have inherited a classic ASP site from a design agency who just wanted us to do a search and replace to change SMTP hosts. No problem, we are a PHP shop but can turn our hands to most things.

On further investigation it was discovered that we need to authenticate with the new SMTP server.

A bit of googling lead us to believe that it is using ASPMail 4 and according to the docs it doesn't do authentication.

http://www.serverobjects.com/comp/Aspmail4.htm

We just googled "SMTPsvg.Mailer" from this call:

```
Set Mailer = Server.CreateObject("SMTPsvg.Mailer")
```

Am I correct in my assumptions that the above is ASPMail 4, and the APSMAil doesn't do authentication?

What can I use to authenticate with a SMTP server if I need to replace Aspmail?

Comment: Just to note, I know nothing about ASP...other than it runs on windows servers and it starts flame wars.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As said, use CDO.

```
set config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
with config.Fields
 .item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort
 .item(sch & "smtpserver") = application("smtpserver")
 .item(sch & "smtpserverport") = application("smtpserverport")
 .item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic auth
 .item(sch & "sendusername") = application("sendusername")
 .item(sch & "sendpassword") = application("sendpassword")
 .update
end with

with CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  .configuration = config
  .to = ...
  .from = ...
  .subject = ....
  .HTMLBody = ....
  call .send()
end with
```

Docs about each field of the config object can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526318(v=exchg.10).aspx)!

Comment: For newbies like me `application("sendusername")` should be defined somewhere else. If you didn't define it before, use it directly like `"blabla@blabla.com"`

Answer (score 1):

Check if the hosting provider supports .Net Framework 2.0 (most do), if so rename the .asp file to .aspx, remove the code that sends the email and write some easy code:

http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/3.8.aspx

Regards

Thomas

Comment: Unfortunately, porting existing ASP pages to ASP.NET pages is almost never as easy as simply renaming the file extension from .asp to .aspx because, among other factors, there are significant differences between Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) and Visual Basic .NET.  from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx

Comment: Not necessarily he need to rewrite the whole page, only making a `mailsender.aspx` that accepts the data needed as POST data, sends the mail and returns a result value. Better than using CDO in my opinion.

Answer (score -3):

According to the docs [here](http://www.serverobjects.com/comp/Aspmail4.htm) ASPMail 4.x just doesn't support authentication.  It looks like you'll have to switch to a different COM-based SMTP component.

Comment: he has given the link in his question :)

Comment: Why exactly does reposting the same link earn a downvote when my answer is otherwise identical to the top-voted question?  Just wondering.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to down vote. However it might be due to the fact you linked to the same docs that i linked to in my question stating the same as I did that the docs say it doesn't support authentication.